# How to parse a value where the class name changes depending on the value?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I have the next html code:

```
       ...   
            <tr class="main">...</tr>
            ...
            <tr class="main">
            
              <td class="int">JJJ</td>
              <td class="int">18</td>
            
              <td class="int">
                   **<span class="plus">20%</span>
                   <span class="minus">-15%</span>**
              </td>
            
              <td class="int">02/06/2022</td>
        
            </tr>
            ...
            <tr class="main">...</tr>
        ...
```

I need to resolve the situation with `<span class="plus">20%</span>` and `<span class="minus">-15%</span>`. In the html code, you can see these two lines, but in real time it works like this: if the value is negative, html only shows the line`<span class="minus">-15%</span>`, if the value is positive, it only shows the line`<span class="plus">20%</span>`

I wrote the parsing code, but how to solve this problem using `if else` and checking span class name or maybe some other way to fix it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    item = soup.find_all('tr', class_='main')
    data = []
    for i in item:
        data.append({
            'percent': i.find('td', class_='int').find_next('td', class_='int').find_next('td', class_='int').get_text()
    print(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion there is no need to check for the `class` cause position of the value is always the same - So simply extract the values from the `<td>` and store it in your list of dicts:

```
data.append(dict(zip(['Name','Amount','Percentage','Date'],row.stripped_strings)))
```

But to answer your question simply use comma (,) to join multiple selectors in a list. When presented with a selector list, any selector in the list that matches an element will return that element - cause there is only one of the classes it will pick the right one:

```
data.append({'percentag':row.select_one('.plus,.minus').text})
```

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<tr class="main">
  <td class="int">AAA</td>
  <td class="int">18</td>
  <td class="int">
       <span class="minus">-15%</span>
  </td>
  <td class="int">02/06/2022</td>
</tr>
<tr class="main">
  <td class="int">BBB</td>
  <td class="int">18</td>
  <td class="int">
       <span class="plus">20%</span>
  </td>
  <td class="int">02/06/2022</td>
</tr>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

data = []
for row in soup.select('tr'):
    data.append(dict(zip(['Name','Amount','Percentage','Date'],row.stripped_strings)))
data
```

###### Output

```
[{'Name': 'AAA', 'Amount': '18', 'Percentage': '-15%', 'Date': '02/06/2022'}, {'Name': 'BBB', 'Amount': '18', 'Percentage': '20%', 'Date': '02/06/2022'}]
```

Comment: This is one line of code very powerful, this example good for work with same name class, Thank You!!!!))))